# how can we authenticate user via user name and password

Tags: twitter

how can we authenticate user via user name and password in my local application in asp.net by which directly we authenticate to do the tweets in  local application which shows on twitter website also...
Please do the needful..

Comment: Why need a user-pass auth? There's a more secure way on authenticating twitter accounts.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to validate a Twitter user via a third-party app using username and password.  Twitter shut down Basic Authentication.  The only avenue available for thir party apps is OAuth.